# Why doesn't VS 2008 IDE remember my preferences?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, preferences

This is  a very petty question that I'm only asking while [compiling](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/compiling.png)... ;)

For some reason my VS 2008 IDE doesn't remember my window preferences when I close & reopen - it resets the window widths, locations, appearances etc.

Where's the secret switch so that my IDE stays looking the way I want it?

Comment: If you do not get a definite reply to this, consider filing a bug (at MS Connect). By design, VS is supposed to save window layout, including that width.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, I did that and got the answer from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resetting the Visual Studio

```
Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset All Settings
```

Or

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

Comment: +1 and answer credit: I logged a support call with Microsoft at http://connect.microsoft.com, and they advised me to do exactly this... and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

The window positions are stored in the following file:

```
%APPDATA%\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\windows.prf
```

I'm guessing that you don't have write access to this file, or something.

Anyway if you can somehow delete this file, it will regenerate it when you next start up your VS, with the windows in their default positions.

Comment: OK, we're on the trail here.  Turns out the only things that are not working properly are the windows docked to the side of the IDE; their widths are not being saved.  Everything is saving correctly.

Comment: Is it any toolwindow you dock onto left/right edge, or only specific ones?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one instance of VS 2008 open? The settings of the last closed instance will overwrite the ones saved before.

Answer (score 1):

Does the initial VS screen come up, asking for an "environment" type? What operating system do you run VS on? More details would probably help to provide some hints...

Comment: No, it doesn't ask for environment type.  I'm on WinXP SP3.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after installing certain plugins. Maybe try to disable your plugins and see if it still happens?

Apart from that, VS itself did not cause any trouble in this aspect for me. Of course, you have to exit VS in the intended way and let it have enough time to save it's settings. Crashing or killing VS in some way naturally prevent this, but I'm sure you knew that already.

Are the symptoms always visible, or is it rather randomly?

**Update**

Are only window settings affected, and other settings can still be changed without problem?
Are you sure you still have write access where needed?
Does it work if you switch over to a different user account (with admin privileges)?

Comment: Nah, even if I disable my add-ins it still happens.  Always.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this very problem, and more or less followed demoncodes advice. Went to

```
%AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0Exp\UserSettings
```

and removed the file `windows.prf` and `backup_windows.prf` (made a copy of it first of course.) Seems to have fixed my problems at least.

Answer (score -2):

There is none. Loosing windows size an position has always been an illness of Windows. VS on its own is not free from it.

There is more: There are settings & preferences in VS, and you can export them for future use. The options for export miss some settings. There has been two years already, they haven't fixed it still.

Comment: But some people ARE able to save their window sizes & positions.  Obviously there's just some difference in settings somewhere that allows you to save your preferences, and I must have something wrong with my configuration that this is not working.

Comment: Not really. It's just something is suddenly broken in windows or in VS and there is no way to find out what. The only option is to reinstall everything hoping it will be better afterwards.

Comment: Let me chime in as a guy on VS team: Windows behavior has nothing to do with VS toolwindows, because they aren't top-level windows. They are controls hosted inside VS, and VS takes full responsibility for managing their width/height, and specifically for saving it.