# vs2010 window layout messed up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

My computer crashed while I had VS2010 open, and when I recovered (all I did was reset the computer) and opened visual studio again, all my layout was messed up. Since I had very little customization done, I figured I would just reset the window layout. I tried Window > Reset Window Layout, but that didn't work. I even tried resetting the environment. How can I get back the default layout that I had right after installing?
Specifically, the changes I notice right away are the Solution explorer/etc. group of windows being on the right instead of the left, and the error reporting/output/code definition windows missing from the bottom. I know that I can just fix these things myself, but I don't know what else I am not noticing that has changed, and therefore would like to see everything reset automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this which worked: [Visual studio forgets window settings and makes a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866820/visual-studio-forgets-window-settings-and-makes-a-mess/866957#866957)