# VS 2010 forgets my customised Fonts and Colours

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I like a dark background when coding and have customised it to a scheme that suits me.  However each time I start VS some colours are wrong.  To fix this I have to go to "Tools\Options\Fonts and Colours", click on "Display items" and click OK.  This fixes it for that session but the next time I start up VS the colours are wrong again.

Clearly the colour scheme is remembered because I don't have to set them again, just having to go through the above process.  Is there any way to fix this problem so that I get the correct colour scheme the first time I start VS?

Comment: This is a rather strange problem. I, too, prefer the Dark Side, and use various customized syntax highlighting schemes in VS. But I've never had a problem with it not remembering my settings. You might try resetting all of Visual Studio's settings (following [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/866957/366904)). I'm not sure where else to tell you to start debugging if that doesn't work. Any more information you can provide?

Comment: I occasionally have issues when a plugin that does highlights changes (Visual Assist X and ViEmu mostly), but going into colors and hitting ok fixes it as well.

Comment: Have you installed a plugin such as Resharper or CodeRush? I have recently upgraded my Resharper installation and found that a subtle change in my editors syntax colors has happened. If you have many plugins, you might want to try removing those and see what happens. It's just about as much fun as bug hunting. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I have Resharper installed and maybe that's what the cause is.  I also noticed over recent weeks that things like when browsing a web page from within VS (like clicking a link on the news casts) also does alter the colours.  Very weird.

Comment: I have this problem as well. All of the settings are correct, but I sometimes have to get VS to "refresh" them by opening up Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, then click OK. I do have Resharper and other add-ons installed; however, I am somewhat skeptical that this is a ReSharper problem but perhaps it is a Visual Studio extensibility problem, i.e. perhaps in general add-ins that add a lot of customized fonts/colors to the list are contributing to a core VS problem? (No specific reason really for my skepticism.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have disappeared. I don't know exactly what did it. Our MSDN license came through and I reinstalled Expression Blend (which might have updated some files for VS and we also got a licensed version of Resharper (I had a trial one only till then and downloaded a slightly newer version after we got the license).