# Missing colors in code editor Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, formatting, visual-studio-2013

Is it just me, or am I missing some colors in my editor? Just noticed and now it annoys the h*ck out of me.
[image: No color]

I'm running VS2013 with Resharper 8 and the default Light theme provdied with it

Comment: Looks totally fine to me

Comment: Aren't reference types and user-defined objects usually highlighted in their own colour?

Comment: What text do you think should be colored there?

Comment: I might be wrong here, or it might be some plugin I've used in VS2012, but should'nt for instance "OperationDataSource" be shaded in a light green-ish? Checked on a colleagues machine with identical setup, and he has the green coloring. Makes we wonder what else is missing in regards to color.

Comment: Try recompiling or verifying if the OperationDataSource type can be seen by the assembly you are working on. Does this happen with any file or just in this case?

Comment: Just rebooted, cleaned solution, rebuild and still no luck. As I mentioned above, a colleague with identical setup just cloned the solution and he has the colors I'm missing. It's also in all my files @SebastianPiu. :/

Comment: Ok, try to reset your VS settings to default then.

Comment: Does not seem to help :(

Comment: What are the color settings in VS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem by following the accepted answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866820/visual-studio-forgets-window-settings-and-makes-a-mess). Thank you so much for your help and suggestions.

For the record (Note `OperationDataSources()`) :
[image]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're missing the color setting for User Types:

[image]

No idea why they're not set by the profile settings.  The defaults for this color are: Hue 129, Sat 145, Lum 103, R 43, G 145, B 175.

Comment: maybe he imported some settings or a plugin changed the default settings. Its an easy thing to fix.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Only one somewhat stupid question. Where do I change this? Tried Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors but could not find "User Types" when "Text Editor" was selected from the dropdown.

Comment: @NicklasWinger hm, you're looking in the right place.  If it's not there, then that's probably why it's not working.  I don't know how those items get registered; have you tried doing a repair of VS?

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy. Definitely something going on here. I'll give it a try once I get back to the office tomorrow!

Answer (score -1):

You have to be aware when adding extensions to a visual studio code, as for example .h .cpp .cu and many other code based files. Visual Studio will most likely just show you no code colors.

You can add extensions in the options from Tools-Opions, and add specific code type to any file that you already changed with explorer for example to notepad or wordpad.